# Proving that a set is a subspace of a given space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have encountered this question and I am wondering whether my thinking is correct. We have vectors $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$ as elements of the space $V$. We have also got a set $U$ is the set of all combinations of $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$. We are proving that $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Solution:

Suppose $x$ is an arbitrary vector in $U$. Vectors in $U$ are linear combinations of $u_1, \dots, u_n$ and therefore $x_i=\alpha_{1_{i}}u_1+\dots+ \alpha_{n_{i}}u_n$. Let $x_j$ be another vector in $U$ and so $x_j=\alpha_{1_{j}}u_1+\dots+ \alpha_{n_{j}}u_n$. Now we need to show that $x_i+x_j \in U$, so: $x_i+x_j=(\alpha_{1_{i}}u_1+\dots+ \alpha_{n_{i}}u_n)+(\alpha_{1_{j}}u_1+\dots+ \alpha_{n_{j}}u_n)$
$x_i+x_j=(\alpha_{1_{i}}+\alpha_{1_{j}})u_1+\dots+(\alpha_{n_{i}}+\alpha_{n_{j}})u_n$.

So that $x_i+x_j$ is a linear combination of vectors $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$ and so $x_i+x_j \in U$. Now we will prove that $\lambda x_i \in U$ for any $\lambda \in K$. 
$x_i=\alpha_{1_{i}}u_1+\dots+ \alpha_{n_{i}}u_n$ and so $\lambda x_i=\lambda(\alpha_{1_{i}}u_1+\dots+ \alpha_{n_{i}}u_n)=\lambda\alpha_{1_{i}}u_1+\dots+ \lambda\alpha_{n_{i}}u_n$. So that $\lambda x_i$ is a linear combination of vectors $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$ and so $\lambda x_i \in U$.

Zero vector is in $U$ as $0_V$ is a linear combination of any vectors, which completes the proof.

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition_and_useful_characterization_of_subspace), I would utilize the theorem stated in the section entitled "Definition and useful characterization."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument lies somewhere between very confusing and entirely incorrect.

---

What you should do:

- Prove that for every pair of elements $x,y\in U$, the element $x+y$ is also in $U$.
- Prove that for every element $x\in U$ and scalar $\alpha\in K$, the element $\alpha x$ is also in $U$.

---

Where you are confusing:

- $u=\alpha_1 u_1,\dots,\alpha_n u_n$. What does this mean? Are you missing some plus signs?
- It looks to me like all you did was take a single vector $u\in U$ and showed that this vector is... an element of $U$. Why did you do that?

Comment: I meant $u=\alpha_1 u_1+ \dots +\alpha_n u_n$ is just any vector in $V$.

Comment: @user239666 In $V$ or in $U$?

Comment: @user239666 Also, the rest of my comments still stand: your argument is not good at the moment. You need to prove that if $x\in U$ and $y\in U$, then $x+y\in U.$ Where did you prove that?

Comment: Isn't that enough to say that $x+y$ is a linear combination of vectors $u_i$ and therefore belongs to the set $U$?

Comment: @user239666 Well yes. But where did you prove that?

Comment: You are right. Sorry.

Comment: @user239666 If you try again, you can edit your question with what you did, and I can look at it again. Just write a comment starting with "@5xum" so I get the notification.

Comment: in You also need to show that if $x \in U$, $\beta \in K$ then $\beta x \in U$. This is similarly simple. And finally you should probably argue that $0 \in U$.

Comment: @JHance Actually, $0\in U$ follows from the fact that $\beta x\in U$ if you set $\beta=0$. It is not necesary to prove that part.

Comment: @5xum I have done it!

Comment: @user239666 Looks very good now! I understand perfectly what you did, and every step logically follows from the previous step. Much better than before. Well done!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can we actually say that zero vector is in $U$ as $0_V$ is a linear combination of any vectors?

Comment: @user239666 It's not really neccesary to prove that $0\in U$. If you want to, the easiest way is to say $0=0\cdot u_1 + 0\cdot u_2 + \cdots + 0\cdot u_n$

Comment: @5xum May I ask you one more question? Do we have to write doube indices as I did when introducing $x_i$? Can we just call it $x=\alpha_1 u_1+\dots$ and $y=\beta_1 u_1+\dots$?

Comment: @user239666 You need to differentiate the factors from $x$ and the factors from $x_i$. Personally, I would say $x=\alpha_1 u_1+\cdots + \alpha_n u_n$ and $y = \beta_1 u_1$ + \cdots \beta_n u_n$ instead of double-indexing. Double indices are also a way to differentiate the two vectors.